# Problems using SQL in conjuction with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

Sorry I am new to this, but heres what I'm trying to do.

This is what I currently have

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but what Im trying to do is this

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE category = categorylabel.Text
```

I have a column in my database called category, and I want only the data thats category type matches a category in a hidden label (or a session) called categorylabel.Text to do this, the label gets updated with the session. It may be unncessary but I couldnt think of how else to do it.

So how would I go about using my session, to make the SqlDataSource1 only display the data in the Products database that has a category matching that session?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE category=@category">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="categorylabel" Name="category" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```